# Выборка пользователей, имена которых начинаются не с буквы

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, каким запросом сделать выборку из базы только тех пользователей, имена которых начинаются не с буквы, а например с цифры или символа (типа 777name, !user).

Таблица users: name - имена.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: `select * from users where name regexp '^[^a-zA-Z]'`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE LEFT( name, 1) < 'a';`

Comment: @rjhdby Во первых большие буквы меньше 'a'. Во вторых в пространстве кодов между буквами есть знаки препинания. http://www.asciitable.com/